# How do I send a javascript object in a querystring?

Tags: javascript, express, query-string

I want to send this javascript object in a query string so that I can use it as an object when received by the server. Currently, I am using an xhr request:

```
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var params = {
            searchParams: {name: 'Joe'},
            sortParam: {name: -1},
            skip: 0,
            limit: 50
        };
        xhr.open('get', '/api/endpoint' + formatParams(params));
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                ...
            }
            else{
                ...
            }
        });
        xhr.send();
```

Where formatParams function is as follows:

```
const formatParams = ( params ) => {
    return "?" + Object
            .keys(params)
            .map(function(key){
                return key+"="+params[key]
            })
            .join("&")
};
```

On the server I am receiving the request via an Express Router, where the parameters are subsequently used in a MongoDB query:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
router.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.searchParams);
    ...
});
```

Currently, the server is showing `req.query.searchParams` as a string

> [object Object]

Comment: what is `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query.searchParams));` showing?

Comment: Also: don't format parameters like this. They need to be url-encoded. If you happen to use jquery, use its jquery.params method which does the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: You need to convert your object to JSON. It Is using the native object toString method.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query.searchParams)); shows "[object Object]"

Comment: I am not using jQuery - what should I use to urlencode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. `key` and `params[key]` should be url-encoded, you can use `encodeURIComponent(...)` for this (it's a standard function)
2. Since `params[key]` is an object in two cases (searchParam, sortParam), the string presentation will be [Object object]. Instead try:  `return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params[key]))`
3. On the server-side, you probably need to run `JSON.parse(req.query.searchParams)` to get your object back